# Which is the best way to create NSString from an int?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, type-conversion, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

Suppose I've this, `int yo = 5;`.

Now I want to convert that to an `NSString`. Here are the possible ways,

```
1) NSString *h = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yo];

2) NSString *k = @(yo).stringValue;

3) NSString *s = [NSNumber numberWithInt:yo].stringValue;

4) any other "best" ways?
```

Which one is the best and why?

Answer (score 0):

The first way is better because it avoids having to create an intermediate instance of NSNumber. Also note that

```
@(5).stringValue;
```

and

```
[@(5) discriptionWithLocale:nil];
```

are equivalent statements.